# Which one is used in the sentence? parallelism or participle cluse

Tags: parallelism, participle-clauses

> A good Captain needs to be steadfast, **continuing** to hold the wheel and **stay** the course even during the most violent storm.

I faced with the above sentence at an App, but I think the parallelism does not respect here. For instance, "continuing" should be "continue", am I right?
If participle clause is used here, I mean "continuing" , then "stay" should be in participle present,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last phrase "stay the course" is more parallel to "hold the wheel", and that both of those phrases are linked to the verb "continuing". So, it's

"continuing to [hold the wheel **and** stay the course]

So, "be steadfast" is accomplished by "continuing" those two things.

I think using "continue" would make that structure less clear.

Comment: Then, we have a participle clause in "continuing" and parallelism in "stay", am I right?

Comment: Yes. The parallelism is between "stay the course" and "hold the wheel".